# Need suggestion to swap key and value of complex json

Tags: java, json

I have the below json

```
{  
   "Roles":[  
      {  
         "January":[  
            {  
               "CN":[  
                  "GoogleCnFeatureOwner",
                  "GoogleCnAnalyst",
                  "SupportAnalyst",
                  "AdminCn"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "EU":[  
                  "GoogleEuFeatureOwner",
                  "GoogleEuAnalyst",
                  "SupportAnalyst",
                  "AdminEu"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "NA":[  
                  "GoogleNaFeatureOwner",
                  "GoogleNaAnalyst",
                  "SupportAnalyst",
                  "AdminNa"
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "February":[  
            {  
               "CN":[  
                  "AbcCnFeatureOwner",
                  "AbcCnAnalyst",
                  "SupportAnalyst",
                  "AdminCn"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "EU":[  
                  "AbcEuFeatureOwner",
                  "AbcEuAnalyst",
                  "SupportAnalyst",
                  "AdminEu"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "NA":[  
                  "AbcNaFeatureOwner",
                  "AbcNaAnalyst",
                  "SupportAnalyst",
                  "AdminNa"
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "March":[  
            {  
               "CN":[  
                  "YahooCnFeatureOwner",
                  "SupportAnalyst",
                  "AdminCn",
                  "UserCn"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "NA":[  
                  "YahooNaFeatureOwner",
                  "SupportAnalyst",
                  "AdminNa",
                  "UserNa"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to implement a method in java to parse the above json and swap the key with value and create a collective json like below.

```
    {
    "WifiCnFeatureOwner": [{
        "CN": ["January"]
    }],
    "ItSupportAnalyst": [{
        "CN": ["January", "February", "March"]
    }, {
        "EU": ["January", "February"]
    }, {
        "NA": ["January", "February", "March"]
    }]
}
```

I'm using org.json APIs to start with. 
Please suggest some best approach to achieve the conversion effectively (without Guava BiMap). I'll post the code once completed anyway.

Comment: `{"Region" : "CN", "EU", "NA"}` is not valid JSON. Did you mean `{"Region" : ["CN", "EU", "NA"]}`?

Comment: Sorry Andreas for the typo. I've corrected it.

Comment: You lost information. `SupportAnalyst` is in all 3 regions for `January` and `February`, but only in two of them for `March`. Your transformed data can't specify that.

Comment: Andreas, Thanks. You have a point. I have edited the question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the `org.json` APIs, here is one way to do it.

I deliberately didn't do exactly the output you wanted, so you'd have to understand the code to modify it. The output below has all the features you wanted, but it is simpler.

```java
byte[] inputBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.json"));
String inputText = new String(inputBytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
JSONObject inputJson = new JSONObject(inputText);
JSONObject outputJson = new JSONObject();
for (Object monthObj : inputJson.getJSONArray("Roles")) {
    JSONObject monthJson = (JSONObject) monthObj;
    for (String monthName : monthJson.keySet()) {
        for (Object regionObj : monthJson.getJSONArray(monthName)) {
            JSONObject regionJson = (JSONObject) regionObj;
            for (String regionCode : regionJson.keySet()) {
                for (Object roleObj : regionJson.getJSONArray(regionCode)) {
                    String roleName = (String) roleObj;
                    JSONObject role = outputJson.optJSONObject(roleName);
                    if (role == null)
                        outputJson.put(roleName, role = new JSONObject());
                    JSONArray region = role.optJSONArray(regionCode);
                    if (region == null)
                        role.put(regionCode, region = new JSONArray());
                    region.put(monthName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(outputJson.toString(3));
```

*Output*

```
{
   "AbcNaAnalyst": {"NA": ["February"]},
   "AbcCnFeatureOwner": {"CN": ["February"]},
   "GoogleNaFeatureOwner": {"NA": ["January"]},
   "UserCn": {"CN": ["March"]},
   "AdminNa": {"NA": [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March"
   ]},
   "GoogleEuAnalyst": {"EU": ["January"]},
   "GoogleCnFeatureOwner": {"CN": ["January"]},
   "SupportAnalyst": {
      "EU": [
         "January",
         "February"
      ],
      "NA": [
         "January",
         "February",
         "March"
      ],
      "CN": [
         "January",
         "February",
         "March"
      ]
   },
   "AbcEuAnalyst": {"EU": ["February"]},
   "YahooNaFeatureOwner": {"NA": ["March"]},
   "UserNa": {"NA": ["March"]},
   "AdminCn": {"CN": [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March"
   ]},
   "AdminEu": {"EU": [
      "January",
      "February"
   ]},
   "GoogleNaAnalyst": {"NA": ["January"]},
   "YahooCnFeatureOwner": {"CN": ["March"]},
   "AbcEuFeatureOwner": {"EU": ["February"]},
   "GoogleEuFeatureOwner": {"EU": ["January"]},
   "AbcCnAnalyst": {"CN": ["February"]},
   "AbcNaFeatureOwner": {"NA": ["February"]},
   "GoogleCnAnalyst": {"CN": ["January"]}
}
```

Manually reformatted for human readability:

```
{
   "AbcCnAnalyst": {
      "CN": ["February"]
   },
   "AbcCnFeatureOwner": {
      "CN": ["February"]
   },
   "AbcEuAnalyst": {
      "EU": ["February"]
   },
   "AbcEuFeatureOwner": {
      "EU": ["February"]
   },
   "AbcNaAnalyst": {
      "NA": ["February"]
   },
   "AbcNaFeatureOwner": {
      "NA": ["February"]
   },
   "AdminCn": {
      "CN": ["January", "February", "March"]
   },
   "AdminEu": {
      "EU": ["January", "February"]
   },
   "AdminNa": {
      "NA": ["January", "February", "March"]
   },
   "GoogleCnAnalyst": {
      "CN": ["January"]
   },
   "GoogleCnFeatureOwner": {
      "CN": ["January"]
   },
   "GoogleEuAnalyst": {
      "EU": ["January"]
   },
   "GoogleEuFeatureOwner": {
      "EU": ["January"]
   },
   "GoogleNaAnalyst": {
      "NA": ["January"]
   },
   "GoogleNaFeatureOwner": {
      "NA": ["January"]
   },
   "SupportAnalyst": {
      "EU": ["January", "February"],
      "NA": ["January", "February", "March"],
      "CN": ["January", "February", "March"]
   },
   "UserCn": {
      "CN": ["March"]
   },
   "UserNa": {
      "NA": ["March"]
   },
   "YahooCnFeatureOwner": {
      "CN": ["March"]
   },
   "YahooNaFeatureOwner": {
      "NA": ["March"]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest against attempting to reinvent the wheel.
Everything you mention that you want to do has already been done in an open source library.

1. Use Jackson (or some other JSON parser) to perform the initial parsing of the JSON.
2. Use a Guava BiMap to get a bidirectional map (should allow you to swap key and value).
3. use Jackson (or other blah) to create the new JSON.

Comment: @Mr.Green My answer may be too simplified for your question.  It now looks like you don't want to invert a map, you want to invert a tree.

Comment: Yes DwB. I have edited the question. Please share your comments or suggestion.